# The Mechanics behind SOFLAM

Tags: battlefield-3

How exactly does the SOFLAM work? Do you always need to be manning it in order to lock on to enemy vehicles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like the MAV and T-UGS, the SOFLAM works either as a manned or unmanned device.

If you place it on a high area with an overlook (ideally), it will automatically scan for and lock on to enemy vehicles in its field of vision. No human intervention required.

I *suspect* that it is more efficient when manned and operated manually -- and you can switch over to your deployed SOFLAM to control it remotely at any time using the proper gadget key -- but it does work either way.

Also note that the SOFLAM survives your death as recon, once deployed it is a permanent battlefield artifact until it is destroyed by the enemy.

Comment: Man T-UGS? Interesting...

Comment: well, I guess I was thinking that the MAV is basically a T-UGS when you aren't manning it..

Comment: Does the SOFLAM gets destroyed if you change class?

Comment: No, as stated earlier, the SOFLAM stays in play until destroyed. You can deploy the SOFLAM early in a game and then switch to Engineer with a Javelin equipped and utilize the SOFLAM.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Jeff here, He forgot the most important part of why the Soflam is the best tool in the game. **IT INCREASES THE POWER OF JAVELENS**. Which is very very deadly.

Do look at this post: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2238182

> When used in conjunction with the SOFLAM, a Javelin shooting at a
>   "Painted" target will do 3x the normal damage

Another advantage i've noticed, Is that you can use guided rockets with the tank to lock on to soflam-ed targets. When firing you can switch back to your normal cannon and fire again. Give you instant kill. Its almost a known secret i don't want to part with. But for the greater good. Have it and use it!