# What are the conditions to get a lock with the Javelin Missile System?

Tags: battlefield-3

In BF3, sometimes I can get a lock over very long distances, using the Javelin Missile System, sometimes I need to be very close.

For that reason, I would like to know all conditions in which I can get a lock on a vehicle with this weapon system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways that you can achieve a solid lock with the Javelin Missile System.  [Take a look at a similar postings about it here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbattlefield-3%5D%20javelin)

## SOFLAM:

The recon class has the ability to to use the SOFLAM which is a laser designator which, *when used properly,* can increase the targeting of the Javelin to roughly 1500 Meters as mentioned by Tony

Check out this previous post by Angel.King.47 [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46472/18818) that mentions:

> Do look at this post:
>   http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2238182
>
> When used in conjunction with the SOFLAM, a Javelin shooting at a
>   "Painted" target will do 3x the normal damage

## Laser Designator:

Tanks and Helicopters can use the unlock of the Laser designator, which again increases the range of the Javelin to roughly 1500 meters.

#### Otherwise:

Tony is correct and through my personal experiences the range of the Javelin alone is between 0-300 meters.   **My recommendation would be to party up or communicate with other players to achieve maximum range and damage while using your Javelin.**

*Note: most recon players with put down a Soflam on request (through my experiences).  I mean who doesn't love more XP?*

Answer (score 1):

Stare at a vehicle long enough to get a lock; this has a fairly limited range. I've read this has a max range of 250-300 meters. From experience this seems about right but I have no source for this. This also requires vision of the vehicle.

According to [this](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-javelin/) a javelin has a max range of 1500 meters. The only way for someone to lock on at this distance is with assistance of a laser designator, this can be a SOFLAM, tank, etc. In this way, there is no need to be able to see the target.